# Airflow 2 - BigQueryInsertJobOperator - how to resolve airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Argument ['configuration'] is required

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow

I am facing the following error while using `BigQueryInsertJobOperator` in Airflow 2.1.4:

`airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Argument ['configuration'] is required`

How to define correctly the configuration?

Code:

```py
    my_bq_task = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
        dag=dag,
        task_id="my_bq_task",
        gcp_conn_id="google_cloud_default",
        configuration={
            "query": "{% include '/sql/load_crm_interactions.sql' %}",
            "destinationTable": {
                "projectId": bq_prj,
                "datasetId": "data_crm",
                "tableId": "interactions",
            },
            "createDisposition": "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
            "writeDisposition": "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
            "allowLargeResults": True,
            "useLegacySql": False
        }
    )
```

traceback:

```
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/dagbag.py", line 326, in _load_modules_from_file
    loader.exec_module(new_module)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/seba/projects/composer/dags/crm/crm_interactions_import.py", line 737, in <module>
    my_bq_task = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 167, in apply_defaults
    raise AirflowException(msg)
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Argument ['configuration'] is required
```

Comment: Please show full traceback

Comment: added traceback

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had resolved this by correcting the JSON specification

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Could you share the working solution as the answer?